# Linq Expressions -> Create CallExpression with Equals using enum types

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to build an `CallExpression` like:

```
f.Equals(s);
```

where, `f` and `t` are `enum SType`.

So,

```
var equalsMethod = typeof(SType).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(SType) });
ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(SType));
var newBody = Expression.Call(expr.Body, equalsMethod, constantExpression);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newBody, expr.Parameters);
```

I don't know, but `equalsMethod` is `Boolean Equals(System.Object)` instead of `Boolean Equals(SType)`.

So, when I want to build `CallExpression` .Net tells me, I'm not able to use an expression of type `SType` for the parameter of type `System.Object` of the method `Boolean Equals(System.Object)`.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `f.Equals(s)` you're really doing:

```
f.Equals((object)s)
```

... because `Enum` and `ValueType` don't overload `Equals`. So basically you need a conversion in there - and you can be clearer about the `Equals` method you're calling, too:

```
var equalsMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(object) });
var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(SType));
var boxed = Expression.Convert(constant, typeof(object));
var newBody = Expression.Call(expr.Body, equalsMethod, boxed);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newBody, expr.Parameters);
```

Admittedly you could probably avoid the separate step, just with:

```
var equalsMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("Equals", new[] { typeof(object) });
// Let this do the boxing for you...
var constant = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(object));
var newBody = Expression.Call(expr.Body, equalsMethod, constant);
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(newBody, expr.Parameters);
```

I haven't tried that, but I suspect it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Jon already described what's wrong with your code. However, I'm wondering why you ever bother creating `MethodCallExpression` to `Equals` method while there is a specific [`Expression.Equal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352749(v=vs.110).aspx) method just for that (well, to be precise, for doing equality comparison):

```
return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(expr.Body, Expression.Constant(value)),
    expr.Parameters);
```

Comment: Note that `Expression.Equal` is a call to `operator==` and not `Equals`. If the expression is compiled they are not guaranteed to be equivalent but it is strongly encouraged. If the expression is used in an EntityFramework/LinqToSql query they are translated identically.